# how to auto fill with composite pattern, polymorphism?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Hi I'm working with composite pattern. I'm going to use this example of Head First Design Pattern to explain https://github.com/bethrobson/Head-First-Design-Patterns/tree/master/src/headfirst/designpatterns/composite/menuiterator

Imagine that every menu and submenu have an Id to indentify, it is 10 length. 
Something like this

```
0100000000 menu_1
0101000000   menu_1's subMenu_1  
0102000000   menu_1's subMenu_2
0102010000     subMenu_2's subMenu_3
0200000000 menu_2
```

And what I have at random is the menu item, but it has an ID, which is a Menu ID to which it belongs. For example

```
0101000000 menuItem_1
0200000000 menuItem_2
```

So MenuItem 1 belongs to Menu 1's SubMenu 1 and MenuItem 2 belongs to Menu 2.

It would be coded like this.

```
menu_1.add(subMenu_1);
   subMenu_1.add(menuItem_1);

menu_2.add(menuItem_2);
```

Now how am I filling the menus?

What I'm doing because of I get only the MenuItems, is that I'm cutting the Id to determine where it belongs.
For example you can see that there two Menus, Menu 1 (0100000000) and Menu 2 (0200000000) so I have to cut the first 2 Strings.

I'm coding like this:

```
class AllMenus implements MenuComponent {

   MenuComponent menu_1
   MenuComponent subMenu_1
   MenuComponent subMenu_2
   MenuComponent subMenu_3
   MenuComponent menu_2

   @Override
   add(MenuComponent menu) {

      if(menu instanceof Menu) {

         super.add(menu)

      } else if(menu instanceof MenuItem) {

         String subId = menuItem.getId().subString(0,2)

         if(subId.equals("01")) {

            if(menu_1 == null) {
               menu_1 = new Menu();
               add(menu_1);
            }

            subId = menuItem.getId().subString(0,4);

            if(subId.equals("0101")) {

               if(subMenu_1 == null) {
                  subMenu_1 = new Menu();
                  menu_1.add(subMenu_1);
               }
               subMenu_1.add(menuItem);

            } else if(subId.equals("0102")) {

               if(subMenu_2 == null) {
                  subMenu_2 = new Menu();
                  menu_1.add(subMenu_2);
               }

               subId = menuItem.getId().subString(0,6);

               if(subId.equals("010201")) {

                  if(subMenu_3 == null) {

                     subMenu_3 = new Menu();
                     subMenu_2.add(subMenu_3);

                  }
                  subMenu_3.add(menuItem);
               }

            }


         } else if(subId.equals("02") {

            if(menu_2 == null) {

               menu_2 = new Menu();
               add(menu_2);
            }
            menu_2.add(menuItem);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is for every MenuItem I get. So as you can see this code is to long just for four Menus,imagine thousands of menu, how can it get better?.
I have read that i should use polymorphism to something that repeat, but I don't know how in this case.

Comment: It really confuses Java people if you give variables names starting with a capital letter. `NamesStartingWithACapital` are reserved for class names. Suggest you fix this; you're more likely to get an answer if we can look at the code without getting a headache.

Comment: Also can you explain in more detail how the ten-digit numbers are supposed to be interpreted? I'm sure I don't see the pattern.

Comment: @slim Hi the pattern is when im using the add() method. Behind there is a iterator and else, MenuItem and Menu implements MenuComponent, The ten- digit numbers is where the menuItem belongs. What is constant are the menus but not menuItems, But to determine where belongs im using subString to determine the way it have to go to add the menuItem to some menu.edited variables name

Comment: Can you update the question to make that clear? "The first four chars of the ID mean..." "The next three chars mean...." -- it's still not clear to me.

Comment: @slim Man I have edited the Ids ... The first two digits mean a node and the next two its child, if it have, so on... The Id increase by 2. All of this is two build the tree. But there is going to be many "if else" if I increase the number of total menus, only to put the menuItem in the right menu

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, I think there's too much assumption of the eventual structure in your code.

In general, number literals in your code should be treated with suspicion - e.g.

```
if(subId.equals("010201")
```

... because it looks like configuration, not code. Of course it's fine to put "configuration" in your code, and sometimes it's practical for that configuration to be program code rather than XML/CSV/JSON/etc.  -- but even then, it's good to have a logical separation between a "config" class and a "code" class. For example your "config" class might just contain a method that returns arrays of strings:

```
public class MenuConfig() {
     public String[][] configs() {
         return new String[][] {
             new String[] {"0100000000", "Main menu"},
             new String[] {"0101000000", "Settings"},
             new String[] {"0101010000", "Look and feel"},
             new String[] {"0102000000", "My account"},
             // etc.
         }
     }
}
```

You're looking to create a tree of submenus -- look for inspiration in code to manipulate trees (e.g. binary trees) -- see how simple the code is and how it doesn't make assumptions beyond the fact that each node has zero or more subnodes.

You're already using polymorphism -- your menus and submenus conform to a common type (I can't tell from your code whether they all have the same concrete type, but in principle I might expect you to have a variety of classes that implement `MenuComponent`.

Your code to process one menu just needs to parse the ID to work out where it's supposed to go, then find the place it needs to go, and insert it:

(I'm presenting the IDs with hyphens to make it easier to read)

```
// split "01-02-03-00-00" into [1,2,3] -- ignoring trailing zeros
List<Integer> path = parse(currentMenu.getId()); 

MenuComponent m = rootMenuComponent;
while(path.size() > 1) {
    m = m.getSubMenu(path.remove(0));
}
m.add(path.remove(0), currentMenu());
```

This simple algorithm assumes that menus are added in the right order -- that is you must have handled `01-02-00-00-00` before `01-02-01-00-00`, or you'll get a null pointer.

If you can't live with that constraint, you need to define what could happen, and decide how to deal with it.

- Actually with your current scheme, sorting the keys alphabetically should be sufficient
- If they're just going to come out-of-order, you could treat the to-do-list of menus to be added as a queue. If a particular item can't yet be added, put it to the back of the queue and retry after processing the rest.
- If you want it not to be necessary to explicitly define intermediate menus, then when `m.getSubMenu(subMenuNum)` returns `null` (because you've implicitly "defined" it in the middle of a path) you'll need to create the missing menu at that point.
- If you want it to be possible to define the same menu more than once (maybe both implicitly and explicitly) then you need `MenuComponent.add()` to handle that case, either by merging or overwriting, depending on your requirement.

Assembling a graph of nodes like this is what Spring dependency-injection does -- handling building the graph in order, when the dependencies are defined in arbitrary order. If your aim is study, keep building your own. If you just want build a composite of menus, consider using Spring (or some other DI framework).